# Número mínimo de modelos parcimoniosos em model-averaging (Hurdle Model)

Tags: r

Ao realizarmos uma análise multi-modelo do Hurdle Model, com o pacote "pscl" do R, qual seria o número mínimo de modelos parcimoniosos? Em minha análise, obtive 2 modelos; isso seria pouco?

Comment: Oi Arthur, para receber respostas boas aqui no stack overflow é preciso que você dê mais detalhes do que você está fazendo. O output que recebeu e etc. Da forma que sua pergunta está dificilmente receberá uma resposta boa.